# TimeZone Example in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, date, timezone

Actually in my Flex Application i'm passing Date(in String format) as well as Timezone(String format) convert into Date type but it is not converting Date type ... it is giving null value and my

sample code like this...

```
       var tzDate:String="20012-12-12";
       var tzString:String=tzComboBox.selectedItem;//hear value GMT+0530
       var startDate:Date = DateField.stringToDate(tzDate+" "+tzString,"YYYY-MM-DD TZD");
       Alert.show(startDate);//hear value giving "Null"
```

The problem is it's not converting Date format...Plz Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use parse function and format date before parsing

```
var tzDate:String="2012-12-12";
var tzString:String="GMT+0530";

var dateformat:DateFormatter = new DateFormatter();
dateformat.formatString = "YYYY/MM/DD";

var dateStr:String = dateformat.format(tzDate) +" "+ tzString;
//dateStr is 2012/12/12 GMT+0530
var startDate:Date =  new Date(Date.parse(dateStr));
Alert.show(startDate.toString());
//Show Date of Local time Zone
//Tue Dec 11 21:30:00 GMT+0300 2012
```

Hopes that Helps

Comment: Thanks a lot...hear showing local time zone time so how to avoid this one also.. actually my application user search data in database i'm sending user data directly to Database in this way it is showing local time zone time means some what confusion ....

Comment: you should use/change-to Server/database timezone when saving data, and when retriving data to show user show it in local timezone, so user can view other time zone data as local, while searching let user to put date in its local time zone and covert it in Server/Database time zone while quering DB